# How to integrate Kali Linux features in Ubuntu

Tags: kali-linux, kubuntu

I have tried [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/), a [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) distribution with very powerful security auditing and hacking features.

Since the distribution is based on Debian like [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), I suppose it should be easy integrate the same features in my Ubuntu installation, but how do I do this and what packages includes Kali?

Comment: given the emphasis on a non-ubuntu distro's features, this is perhaps more appropriate to our fellow stackexchange friends Unix & Linux.

Comment: The "how to integrate into Ubuntu" kind of boiled down to "what's in Kali"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Kali, "tool" seems to mean "package". They have a list of all their "tools" here http://tools.kali.org/tools-listing with each one having a little info & links to it's homepage & a kali git page, and what other tools it includes.

I guess you could find & install each tool into whatever OS you prefer, but there are a lot of them, with many not in Ubuntu's default repos, so an `apt-get install` may not always work.

They also have [a page showing their default repos](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories), but I'm not at all confident that just adding them to Ubuntu (or any other linux) would work. Currently, they are:

```
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
 deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: I have tried to add these repo now I get always this error
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255

Comment: Yeah, sounds about right. Kali != Ubuntu

Comment: I tried adding the 2 repo lines to my sources.list in Linux Mint 17 and it didn't work either, caused size mismtaches with packages also in other repos, couldn't install most things at all. Managed to get `bluelog` to install, but those repos aren't really compatible with Ubuntu